# Example with discreteMapper

Tags: cytoscape-web

I'd like to use the discreteMapper of CytoscapeWeb 2.0 (that is, the jQuery-based CytoscapeWeb) but need some example code showing what exactly I have to do.

I already tried with some code taken from the Flash-based CytoscapeWeb and tried

> ```
> var entityColorMapper = {
>     attrName: "etype",
>     entries: [ { attrValue: "protein", value: "#ff0000" },
>                { attrValue: "compound", value: "#00ff00" },
>                { attrValue: "group", value: "#0000ff" } 
>              ]
> };
> ```

and then in the "style" structure I have

> ```
>     "node.E": {
>         fillColor: {
>             discreteMapper: entityColorMapper
>         }
>     }
> ```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's different in Cytoscape Web 2:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscapeweb/wiki/StyleObject

```
  // example discrete mapper
  fillColor: {
    defaultValue: "grey",
    discreteMapper: {
      attr: "type", // field in ele.data() to map to
      mapped: {
        "foo": "red", // field value : visual property value
        "bar": "blue"
      }
    }
  }
```

You don't really need to use a discrete mapper, since you could be using selectors in your style:

```
"node[type='foo']": { fillColor: "red", borderColor: "pink" },
"node[type='bar']": { fillColor: "blue" }
```

It's better to use the second approach, since you can separate the style for `[type='blah']` for several visual properties at once (e.g. `borderColor`), much like CSS.

Remember: Make sure to always work with the latest prerelease version while Cytoscape Web 2 until the first official release is made.
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscapeweb/downloads

Comment: Ah, this is a great tip, it did not appear to me... Thanks!